# Batch Script: Append to Text file based on variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to add lines of text to a text file based on variables that the batch-script user has entered.

My code reads

```
if /I "%cred%" == "modified" Tagging Modified >> info_%id%.txt
if /I "%cred%" == "source" Tagging Source >> info_%id%.txt
```

This doesn't seem to work. 4 lines after this I start using the normal

```
@echo ---- >> info_%id%.txt
```

And the script crashes before it can reach that line

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK] I suggest you edit your question to include a [mcve] with the exact error msg.

Comment: `Tagging ` is not a valid command. Did you miss `echo`?